# Unix Command Execution from Button - XCode Objective - C

Tags: xcode, unix, button, command, execution

Hi I'm having trouble executing a Unix Command from a Button.

This is what I have so far:

```
> #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
> 
> @interface  PUPController : NSWindow { }
> - (IBAction)OpenPUP:(id)PUPC;
> - (IBAction)DestinationFolder:(id)PUPC;
> - (IBAction)Exit:(id)PUPC;
> - (IBAction)Unpack:(id)PUPC;
> 
> @end
> 
> #import "OPDFPUE.h"
> 
> @implementation PUPController
> 
> - (IBAction)OpenPUP:(id)PUPC; {
>     NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"PUP", nil];
>     NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
>     [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
>     [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
>     [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
>     [openDlg setMessage:@"Select Playsation 3 System Software Update (PUP) File for Extraction"];
>     if ( [openDlg runModalForTypes:fileTypes] == NSOKButton )
>     {
>         NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];
>     }
>     NSString * tvarDirectory = [openDlg directory];
>     NSString * tvarFilename = [openDlg filename]; }
> 
> - (IBAction)DestinationFolder:(id)PUPC; {
>     NSSavePanel *saveDlg  = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
>     [saveDlg setMessage:@"Select folder to save extracted contents of the Playsation 3 System Software Update (PUP) File selected"];
>     int tvarInt   = [saveDlg runModal];
>   
>     if(tvarInt == NSOKButton){
>     }
>     else if(tvarInt == NSCancelButton) {
>     return;
>     }
>     else {
>     return;
>     }
>     NSString * tvarDirectory = [saveDlg directory];
>     NSString * tvarFilename = [saveDlg filename]; }
> 
> - (IBAction)Exit:(id)PUPC; {
>     exit(0); } NSTask *pupunpack;
> 
> - (IBAction)Unpack:(id)PUPC {
>     
>     pupunpack=[[NSTask alloc] init];
>     [pupunpack setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/pupunpack"];
>     [pupunpack launch];
>      }
>      
>      - (id)init {
>     
>      } @end
```

If anyone could help that would be great. Basically what I'm doing is inserting a file, setting the destination then the program will unpack that file. I have a open dialog to select a pup file, then a save dialog to select the save destination. I then have the unpack button which currently does nothing. The unpack button requires the arguments  . If anyone could help that would be great.

I'm new to Objective - C, and I have tried to find as much information as I can about this, but i can't seem to get it working. Here's the unix application I am using.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43729201/pupunpack.zip

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add your file name and destination directory as command arguments:

```
[pupunpack setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tVarFilename, tvarDirectory, nil]];
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but i got an error saying "Expected Identifier"

Comment: Now it says: Use of undeclared identifier tvarFilename;  and the same for tvarDirectory

Comment: I got it working from set directory: `NSTask *pupunpack;

- (IBAction)Unpack:(id)PUPC {
    
    pupunpack=[[NSTask alloc] init];
    [pupunpack setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/pupunpack"];
    [pupunpack setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/Users/Hamish/PS3/OFW/"];
    [pupunpack setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"PS3UPDAT355.PUP", @"PS3UPDATE355", nil]];
    [pupunpack launch];
    
     }` Now just to implement the directories that are set via Open Dialog and Save Dialog.

Comment: I think you are just interested in the file name from NSOpenPanel and in the directory from NSSavePanel. Define 2 properties tvarFilename and tvarDirectory in your header file and then use them, removing the current local declarations.

Comment: Ah yes, I want to put my code in, but not sure how to in the comments. I do have a few other questions as well.

Comment: Should I ask the questions here?

Comment: No, create other questions. I wanted to mean that you should accept this question if you think that it helped, maybe it would be usefull also to other users. This is the way stackoverflow works.

Comment: Oh ok, should I post the modified code here, if so how would I do that?